# new Capistrano version 2.6.0 deploy error: `sync' is not implemented by Capistrano::Deploy::SCM::None (rsync with remote cache)

Tags: capistrano

I'm using Capistrano along with the capistrano_rsync_with_remote_cache gem when deploying applications.

The problem occourred after upgrading the deploy server with new software:
capistrano 2.5.10 -> 2.6.0
capistrano_rsync_with_remote_cache 2.3.6 -> 2.4.0
ruby 1.8.6 -> 1.8.7
ruby-gems 1.3.5 -> 1.3.7

the error message:

http://pastebin.com/bD3azxFZ

The top most error:

> /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/capistrano-2.6.0/lib/capistrano/recipes/deploy/scm/base.rb:94:in `sync':` sync' is not implemented by Capistrano::Deploy::SCM::None (NotImplementedError)  from
>
> /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/capistrano_rsync_with_remote_cache-2.4.0/lib/capistrano/recipes/deploy/strategy/rsync_with_remote_cache.rb:110:in

The line from the file rsync_with_remote_cache.rb:110:

> source.sync(revision, local_cache_path)

However this is the same line used in the previous version (2.3.6) of capistrano_rsync_with_remote_cache where the NotImplementedError isn't pressent.

The deploy.rb file used with both versions

http://pastebin.com/EbPkCxyN

what should I change in order to make it deploy again with the newer version?

Comment: I just ran into the same issue. Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: @toneplex in case you still run into this, check my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Sync only works when an SCM is set. You have `set :scm, :none` in your `deploy.rb`. Change it accordingly to your SCM. `set :scm, :git` or the like…

Just had the same error here and got it fixed and thought more people might run into this - and apparently do.

Comment: So you can't use rsync because you're not pulling from an SCM? This doesn't make much sense in my mind...

Comment: I think to OP wants without scm